# Line Integral defined on arbitrary curve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the vector field $F = \left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)$ and let $\gamma: [0,1] \to \Omega$, be a $C^1$ path, where $\Omega = \{(x, y) : y>0\} \cup \{ (x, y) : x<0 \}$, and $\gamma(0) = (1, 1)$, $\gamma(1) = (-1, -1)$. I know that the answer is $\pi$, because we are integrating the angle form, but how do I show it using only calculus?

Comment: On the domain specified the vector field is conservative. So pick an easy path to parametrize and calculate that. Or you can use Green's theorem to prove that every path in the domain between the two points will evaluate to the same number.

Comment: The book I'm working with asked to prove this before introducing conditions in which fields with curls 0 are conservative, so I guess it is asked to prove this without using the fact you said

Comment: It doesn't work because this scalar function is not defined in all of $\Omega$

Comment: @user480840 that is correct. I was just responding to the previous comment. Did not notice the domain.